# Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` i have already set it to true and false

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, android-12

Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

In Maniefest File
i Have already set it to

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nearxt">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />


    <application

        android:label="NearXT"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA_unpQsav6JlIszXYqGH9E19CMMe_Wo0w"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />

<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    </application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have another activity that has an intent filter? Can you add your full AndroidManifest?

Comment: yes give me a minute

Comment: Added the full android Maniefest file please take a look @MiftakhulArzak

Comment: Please make sure all activity tags  and service tags should have properties "android:exported" with value true and it should be main manifest file

Comment: Yes, try to add exported to `com.facebook.FacebookActivity`.

Comment: ok let me make sure of that! @HardikMehta

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak if it is creating any problem i can remove that.

Comment: I mean `<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"` tag

Comment: yes @MiftakhulArzak i have added it.

Comment: still same problem @MiftakhulArzak

Comment: I think there is no problem in your manifest. You've added exported in all activity. May it caused a library. Do you use flutter_local_notifications?

Comment: yes i am using 
can you help me out on any desk or on team viewer or may be on whatsapp?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12